# How to send a value in a Python file to another Python file

Tags: python, async-await

I've been programming in Python recently

I have 2 python file A.py and B.py

in B.py i have the following code

B.py

```
import A
import ...

async def main():
    cc = 'ethusdt'
    url = f'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams={cc}@miniTicker'
    async with websockets.connect(url) as client:
        while True:
            data = json.loads(await client.recv())['data']

            event_time = time.localtime(data['E'] // 1000)
            event_time = f"{event_time.tm_hour}:{event_time.tm_min}:{event_time.tm_sec}"
            date_time = event_time
            price = float(data['c'])
            A.reciv_data(date_time,price))
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

A.py

```
def reciv_data(a,b):
    x=a
    y=b 
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

Which constantly receives information from the server and prints it

I need B.py information in A.py so that when i run A.py first B.py start running and constantly receive information and in A.py give me to do those calculations
Given that the data in B.py is constantly being updated, how can I have this data in A.py ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: You can try writing data to a file or linux socket, or a normal socket

Comment: What data do you need to share between `A.py` and `B.py`? Can you add some more detail? I see `B.py` already imports `A.py` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right - when you run A.py first, you want to actually get B.py up and running as that is the "starting point" of your data flow?

Suggest modifying A.py like so

```
def reciv_data(a,b):
    x=a
    y=b 
    print(x)
    print(y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    subprocess.call('B.py', shell=True)
```

I don't *think* you need to worry about pipes etc here. But could be wrong on that.